# Selenium Logs me out every time when I navigate to a new page, how do I stop this from happening?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium Via Python. I have selenium opening up a webpage using chrome and logging me in.  Then as soon as i click on something else, it logs me out.

For instance. I can run my program to load Reddit.com and log me in. Then as soon as i click to navigate to any post (Whether using selenium to navigate, or stopping my program and clicking on one myself) it logs me out of reddit.  I need it to keep me logged in. Anyone have any clue why its logging me out, and how to fix it?

EDIT: Ok, so I think this is only happening "most" of the time. Sometimes it will keep me signed in and i can navigate all around the website without issue. But most of the time it will log me out as soon as i click on anything. Anyone have any ideas what could be causing this?